# How to track Client id/Application ID from JWT token

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

How to track Client id/Application ID , while making request to API .NET core using JWT token Log this Client ID in Application Insights.

In controller action method i wrote code get client ID. But where i can log this client ID globally. So that I can Log in Application Insights.

```
string accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization]; 
string token = accessToken.Remove(0, 7);
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var decodedValue = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
var clientId = decodedValue.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type=="appid").Value;
```

Comment: add a middleware wherein you read JWT, extract client id and then log it in appinsights. In appsights you could view all logs for a particular request including this client id log

Comment: So what u are looking for is the way to decode jwt token to obtain the appId contained in the token?

Comment: Please include an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: In controller action method able to read jwt token and decoding it. From here i'm getting client ID. But i want to do it either in Base controller or in StartUp.cs

Comment: In Controller action i wrote below code :

Comment: string accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
            string token = accessToken.Remove(0, 7);
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var decodedValue = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
            var clientId = decodedValue.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "appid").Value;

Comment: At the end my Requirement is i want to Log Client ID from all incoming requests , i want to track in application insights

Answer (score 0):

On your description, you hope to use application insights to log appid, so if you don't mind to use custom properties, you could use ITelemetryInitializer to achieve it. Below is my sample code. And don't forget to add linecode in startup.cs. Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-a-custom-property) related.

```
//startup.cs to AddSingleton    
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
                // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
                services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RefererTelemetryInitializer>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

//create ITelemetryInitializer
public class CustomPropertyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private const string HeaderNameDefault = "Referer";

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public RefererTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            if (httpContextAccessor == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));

            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            if (context == null)
                return;

            var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            //add your decode code here
            telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["appid"] = accessToken.Remove(0, 7);
            
        }
    }
```